# Paytm test API keys not found in PayTM dashboard

Tags: api, paytm

After clicking on generate Test API Keys in Paytm Dashboard, it just kinda loads and stops. On reloading the area where my test api details should be present, is just empty. I have also applied for production API keys but I don't know when I will receive them. Any idea on how to get my test api keys?

I tried creating multiple account, incase there was some glitch in my earlier account but I received the same result in all 4 accounts so it has to be some server side problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am having the same issue for the paytm . But I have a test keys which i found in some website and it worked fine for me, try them , it migth help you. Try these : 
PAYTM_MERCHANT_ID = 'DIY12386817555501617'
PAYTM_SECRET_KEY = 'bKMfNxPPf_QdZppa'

Comment: @misra do you get any idea??